# Change key of caps-lock to a R key

Tags: keyboard

The R key on my keyboard is broken, so I changed the key of caps-lock to a R key
by editing:

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc
```

as

```
key <CAPS> {    [ r     ]   };
```

Then reboot.

Unfortunately, it could only literally input the lower-case r, shift+r not works.

How could solve the problem?

Comment: { [ r R ] }; second position (capital r) is when you press it with shift which you need to specify..

Comment: thank you very much, and it's {[ r, R]}